# Blueimp Gallery pinch to zoom on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, blueimp

I am implementing a Blueimp Gallery on my site. I wonder if it is possible to enable pinch to zoom on mobile devices. Right now the gallery works, but one a phone the images are quite small. Mabye this is not possible and a "No" as an answer would be great, but it drives me somewhat crazy.
Thanks

here is the site as it is at the moment. (please be kind, I am not a programmer)
https://simonmenner.com/

Comment: I can at least tell you that there is no easy way to do it, the documentation makes no mention of it...